# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de variables con AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

Me gustaría saber de qué forma puedo obtener el valor de una variable **$mensaje** en **php:**

```
<?php
  if(conficion){
    $mensaje="correcto";
  }else{
    $mensaje="error";
  }
?>
```

Y evaluarlo en **AJAX:**

```
$.ajax({  
        url:"archivo.php",  
        method:"POST",  
        data:
        {
            //================
        },
        dataType:"text",  
        success:function(data)  
        {  
            if(variable_php=="correcto"){
                // Setencias...
            }
            if(variable_php=="error"){
                // Setencias...
            }
        }  
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que archivo.php sea algo parecido a:

```
<?php
    if(conficion){
        $data['message'] = "correcto";
    }else{
        $data['message'] = "error";
    }

    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Podrías evaluarlo en el cliente, mediante ajax, de esta manera:

```
$.ajax({  
    url:"archivo.php",  
    method:"POST",  

    data:
    {
        //================
    },
    dataType:"json",  
    success:function(data)  
    {  
        if(data.message == "correcto"){
            // Sentencias...
        }
        if(data.message == "error"){
            // Sentencias...
        }
    }  
});
```

Aunque hay muchas formas de hacerlo, esta en concreto te permite ampliar el contenido de la respuesta que devuelve el servidor de forma sencilla (únicamente, añadiendo índices al $data) Y es bastante autodescriptivo a simple vista.