# ¿Cómo cambiar un texto de html y asignarle un valor de php?

Tags: php, html, string, variables

Me gustaría saber como puedo tomar un texto de html y asignarle el valor que tengo guardado en una variable de php

```
<h4>El resultado es: </h4>
```

Supongamos que tengo una variable de php así:

```
$resultado=("El resultado es: ", numero);
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para mostrar "$resultado"?

Comment: Bienvenido, deberías dar un vistazo al [Recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funciona el sitio. He dejado una respuesta con algunas opciones de las que dispones. Cualquier duda, solo tienes que preguntar. Un saludo.

Comment: Puede que lo que necesites lo puedas conseguir usando AJAX, en este mismo sitio hay muchas preguntas y respuestas usando esta tecnología, como esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39300/c%c3%b3mo-obtener-el-valor-de-variables-con-ajax?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Tienes varias opciones, entre ellas puedes encontrar:

#### echo

Puedes imprimir todo en *PHP* con comillas dobles que interpreta las variables dentro de las comillas.

```
<?php 
$numero = 4;
echo "<h4>El resultado es: $numero</h4>"; 
?>
```

Puedes imprimir todo en *PHP* con comillas simples que **no interpreta** las variables dentro de las comillas. Por lo que obliga a concatenar la cadena. [Más información sobre el uso de las comillas en *PHP*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/93234/5984)

```
<?php 
$numero = 4;
echo '<h4>El resultado es: ' . $numero . '</h4>'; 
?>
```

Puedes imprimir solo la variable entre el *html*. Pero el archivo debe tener extensión *.php* o *.phtml*. (No recuerdo si hay más extensiones)

```
<?php $numero = 4; ?>
<!-- /... -->
<h4>El resultado es: <?php echo $numero; ?></h4>
```

[Más información acerca de `echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

#### print

Las comillas funcionan igual en la mayoría de los casos.

```
<?php
$numero = 4;
print "<h4>El resultado es: $numero</h4>"; 
?>
```

[Más información acerca de `print`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php)

#### printf

Un tipo de impresión con formato.

```
<?php 
$numero = 4;
printf('<h4>El resultado es: %s</h4>', $numero); 
?>
```

Admite más argumentos y permite cambiar el orden o repetirlos.

```
<?php
$numero = 4;
$numero2 = 10;
printf('<h4>El resultado es: %s de %s</h4>', $numero, $numero2); 
?>
```

[Más información acerca de `printf`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.printf.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$numero = 0;
$resultado = "El resultado es: ".$numero;
echo "<h4>$resultado</h4>";
```

Aunque, si lo que quieres interactuar con el DOM, una vez servida la pagina. Php no es el lenguaje que tienes que utilizar.

Answer (score -1):

Tengo una pregunta similar, tengo un formulario pero cuando le doy enviar la respuesta se pone al final de la pagina, existe alguna función para en una etiqueta html asignar lo que paso en el PHP y asi  modificar su ubicación en la pagina.
En la imagen se ve la pregunta y la respuesta al final, lo que quiero es que salga abajito de la pregunta.

Comment: Hola, no uses el área destinada a las respuestas para formular una pregunta, en lugar de eso, te recomiendo que abras una pregunta nueva. O si lo consideras oportuno, un comentario a la pregunta.